# How to remove polyurethane from painted wall

Tags: cleaning, polyurethane

I forgot to tape around a shelf that I covered with polyurethane and some got on my painted wall.

I'm not sure what kind of paint it is but it will buff off with a wet cloth if you rub it too much, revealing the paper of the drywall sheet.

How can I remove it without removing the paint?

Comment: You won't. Anything that would dissolve the urethane would destroy the paint. Touch up the paint.

Comment: If it were me .. I would let the poly dry and then sand it off, and then repaint the wall..

Comment: The paint sounds like a fairly cheap "latex"/acrylic. Get matching color and try some touch-up by feathering it in. Failing that you'll have to repaint the whole wall. Assuming you don't have a textured wall, you can sand before that, like Ken says.